# Adding fields to JS array

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototypejs, to-json

I've added a field "max" to the JS array prototype. I'm having trouble seeing this addition when I stringify the array. I've tried to overwrite the toJSON function but to no avail.

```
Array.prototype.max = 0;
Array.prototype.toJSON = function(){
    var o = this;
    o.max = this.max;
    return o;
};

var a = [1,2,3];
a.max = 10;

console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
//'[1,2,3]'
```

I'd like to avoid doing something like {array_field:a,max_field:max} and just use the array object - is this possible? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do here? Do you know what `prototype` does, and what the `Array` constructor is ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/nXHmh/

Comment: Yes. I need an additional field for arrays. This works as intended on the server but when I try to "stringify" the arrays and send them to the client my additional field is left out.

Comment: You're not adding anything to the array, only to the Array constructors prototype ?

Comment: I want all arrays to have a "max" field I can access through ".max". I've accomplished this locally. The problem is with reflecting this modified "array thing" remotely when converting the "array thing" to a JSON string.

Comment: Arrays can't have a max field, there are no key/value pairs in arrays, only numeric indices. If you want keys that reference values, use an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options here, none of them will do exactly what you want.

Since JSON arrays are strictly limited to integer keys[1], you can't send down the value of `max` directly.

Your choices include:

- Using an `object` instead of an `array`.  You loose all of the array magic, but it might work better for you.
- Send down meta-data outside your array, such as a configuration object that includes both `max` and your array values
- Force the array to be `max` long before sending it down.  JSON will encode unused array elements with `null`.
- Use a custom serialzer/deserializer.  You could even code things in `JSONS` + the extras. In reality, this pretty much turns out the same as the second option.

[1] Unlike JavaScript Objects

Comment: That's disappointing. I guess I'll just wrap the array in an object.